# Iterating through the Circular linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

[image]

I am dealing with the following problem.
I have created a circular list, and i am also able to create x number of nodes for the number of people required in the circle. I am however stuck as i do not know how exactly i will iterate through the list for every nth person(node). I think i will need to create my own iterator but not sure how to go about it. I know it might be possible to import one from library but i don't want to do that as that will kill the learning process for me.

**Here is the code for my Node Class**

```
public class Node {

    public int iData;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int x) {
        iData = x;
    }

    public void displayNode() {
        System.out.print(iData + " ");
    }

}
```

**Here is the code for Circular Linked List**

```
public class CircularList {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    private Node current;
    private int count; // total items in the list
    public CircularList getCurrent;

    public CircularList() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        current = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void step() {
        current = current.next;
    }

    public Node getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void insert(int x) {
        Node newNode = new Node(x);

        if (isEmpty()) {
            first = newNode;
            current = first;
        } else {
            current.next = newNode;
        }

        newNode.next = first;
        last = newNode;
        step();
        count++;
    }

    public boolean search(int x) {
        Node search = first;
        int y = 0;

        while (search.iData != x && y < count) {
            search = search.next;
            y++;
        }

        if (search.iData == x) {
            System.out.println("Found the value: " + search.iData);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Value not found in list");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void delete(int x) {
        Node prev = first;
        Node curr = first.next;
        int y = 0;

        while (y < count && curr.iData != x) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }

        if (count == 1) {
            first = null;
            count--;
        } else {
            prev.next = curr.next;
            count--;
        }

    }


    public void displayList() {
        int x = 0;
        Node printer = first;

        while (x < count) {
            printer.displayNode();
            printer = printer.next;
            x++;
        }

    }

}
```

**Here is the code for my Josephus Class**

```
public class Josephus {

    private int numOfPeople; // number of people in a circle
    private int countNum; // number used for counting off
    CircularList circle;

    public Josephus() {
        circle = new CircularList();
        numOfPeople = 0;
        countNum = 0;
    }

    public void setNumOfPeople(int x) {
        numOfPeople = x;
    }

    public int getNumOfPeople() {
        return numOfPeople;
    }

    public void setCountNum(int x) {
        countNum = x;
    }

    public int getcountNum() {
        return countNum;
    }

    public void addPeople(int x) {
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            circle.insert(i);
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        circle.displayList();
    }

}
```

I need guidance in the right direction as to what i should do now. I do not ask for code or the answer. i want someone to push me towards the solutions. I can't go to sleep unless i solve this tonight.

Comment: After giving this about 5 minutes of thought, my best guess is you create an index variable where it hold the number of nodes in order. So if you delete the 5th element then the (6th) element after the one you just deleted is now the 5th one. Does that make sense? From there you can tell your program when to stop iterating.

Also, I don't think your delete function works correctly in the case of deleting the first node. That will be the first step you need to fix because you will get nowhere if you cannot delete elements properly.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi you are correct i need to fix my delete method first i just tested it and realized it does not delete the first element..any suggestions

Comment: @ChrisTarazi I figured it out and i am almost done solving the problem i feel so good :D

Comment: Please do post your answer here if you figure it out.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60934/josephus-problem-in-java @ChrisTarazi it seems i have not solved it all the way i have to take it a step further u can read comments people posted.